# Is it possible to use D3 JS to create custom widgets in Hue?

Tags: d3.js, hue

We can create custom D3 js panels on Banana by porting them to a format as required by banana.

https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/wiki/Tutorial:-How-to-Build-a-Custom-Panel

Is there any way to achieve the same in Hue? It doesn't necessarily have to be d3.js but any other visualization tools that I can explore would also be helpful.

I am using Hue for visualizing solr data and am trying to explore more visualizations than the ones already built-in.

Comment: Which visualizations did you have in mind?

Comment: One of the visualizations I'm trying to implement is the sunburst

http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

Comment: Thanks! Will see if it would make sense in the roadmap, nice for pivot/nested data! https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2173

Comment: Thats great!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you need to edit the Hue code directly. The closes available now is to have a custom HTML result widget: http://gethue.com/enhance-search-results/.

Comment: Thank you!! I am currently trying the custom HTML widget.

Comment: I tried the html widget to display a custom d3js visualization. It seems to work except for the fact that the visualization is displayed as many times as there are number of rows instead of just once. This seems to be built into Hue as I don't suppose the HTML widget was built for this. Is there any way round this?

Comment: No, as of today the other way would be to add yourself a new widget in the UI

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Are there any tutorials on how I would be able to do that?